# Find out where Python object was created

Tags: python, memory-leaks

Is there a way to find out where a Python object was instantiated the first time? Like the line number or even the full traceback at the creation?

For memory profiling I'd like to examine all objects after the run. (I'm aware of memory profiling tools, but they are hard to install or don't do this task).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in native Python to obtain this information from an object after it's been created, but you can override the `__new__()` method on a base class to record it somewhere on the object (getting it from the `inspect` module).

Comment: The problem is that it's mostly about lists and dict. So I suppose I need to rewrite all the code or can I override for all `[]` and `{}` automatically?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't easily override `[]` and `{}` literals automatically. You'd have to wrap the literals in a call to a custom list or dict class.

Comment: You could look at the `ast` module and detect all List and Dict literal nodes, in the Load context, and replace those programmatically.

Comment: Yeah... that is the opposite of easily though!

Comment: I actually tried the approach with override classes. But if I have to rewrite code then I could just as well track the `id` of the relevant objects - I noticed :) What a pity. Load context sounds tough. Just out of interest: how do I access it?

Comment: @kindall: true, but maybe you can write a script that uses `ast` to detect List and Dict nodes in the Load context and print what lines they are on. Just to make sure you don't miss one.